# Does a way exist to check if an observable is hot or cold?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there a method in rxjs 4 or 5 to check if an observable is hot or cold?

Comment: More informative title. Unfortunately, it will be probably not enough. I would suggest to explain in at least 2-3 lines, what have you tried and what obstacles you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would need to understand your source when you are building your stream. Downstream Observers should not care about the temperature of the `Observable`. They should only react to what the source is emitting, not the implementation or specific behavior of the source as that would break the separation of concerns.

See [Hot vs. Cold](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md#cold-vs-hot-observables)

Comment: What if I want to validate in a unit test that I'm producing a cold/hot observable? It changes the behavior dramatically, so I think it's important to check.

Comment: That would be the part about understanding your source.  From inside a stream it makes very little difference. There's very not much utility in knowing if the source is hot or cold down stream and it would almost certainly be an anti pattern to have to determine it at run time. If you _had_ to validate the run time characteristics of a source in a test you could do so in a behavior-driven fashion by checking if the subscriptions are idempotent.